# Changing the default mod_policy in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have seen that default `mod_policy` is set to **Admins** policy at that level of configuration, however if I want to set it to **MyPolicy** (which may be any custom valid policy) then how to do that?

Can I achieve it in configtx.yaml itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this successfully by following the below steps:

1. Started the `fabric-samples/first-network`.
2. Perform `docker exec` into the `cli` container.
3. Set the environment corresponding to `peer0.org1.example.com` and that organization's admin user: `Admin@org1.example.com`. Fetch the latest application channel (here `mychannel`) configuration block.
4. Edit the decoded JSON block by changing the `mod_policy` value under the `policies` section for the `Org1MSP` under the `Application` group. Change it from `Admins` to `Readers`.
5. Submit the channel update transaction by encoding and signing the delta block into a protobuf envelope.

Now, our task is to verify this new `mod_policy` is working fine or not. For this, do the following:

1. Set the `cli` environment to `peer0.org1.example.com` and that organization's user: `User1@org1.example.com`. Fetch the latest application channel (here `mychannel`) configuration block.
2. Edit the decoded JSON block by changing the `Readers` policy in the `Org1MSP` from `"OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"` to `"OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer')"` by keeping the JSON syntax of policies in mind.
3. Submit the channel update transaction. The successful update denotes that the `Readers` policy (the new `mod_policy` for that section) was satisfied as we submitted the channel update on behalf of the `User1@org1.example.com` (a `client` user). Note that while updating channel configuration at this moment, the `Readers` policy will be evaluated as `"OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"` as the update has not been processed.
4. Now using the same `cli` environment, try to fetch the latest application channel configuration block. The following error appears:

   `2020-04-09 22:25:48.990 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
    2020-04-09 22:25:49.001 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Got status: &{FORBIDDEN}`

This is because now to **read** the configuration block, `User1@org1.example.com` with client OU won't be able to satisfy the new `Readers` policy i.e. `"OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer')"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be done. You can check the [article](https://medium.com/@arora.aditya520/implementing-and-updating-access-control-lists-for-hyperledger-fabric-83b57a5da1e) which shows how to create a new custom policy and how to update the ACL from `configtx.yaml` only.

Comment: Aditya, I wish to change particularly the **mod_policy** of the configuration which is not part of any ACL.

Comment: It's already mentioned in the article, you can add or edit the policy in configtx.yaml before spinning up the network, but if you want to change it in run-time, you have to do it like mentioned on this [page](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/channel_update_tutorial.html).

Comment: Aditya, **mod_policy** is not set by us, they by default take it as the "Admins" policy. The second link you mentioned suggests changes in the channel configuration. But can we edit the "mod_policy" line inside that decode JSON block? I don't think so that is allowed. That is what I want to confirm from HLF devs.